# I had a vague question on SO

Tags: discussion

So I had a SO question and when starting to get ready write it I noticed that it would have been very vague. So I worked hard for a long time (lots of bing) and figured it out. Then wanting to help out anyone else who had the same question I did the Q&A button. I get on today and noticed I had lost 18 rep from downvotes :( why do people downvote questions that the asker took time to figure it out themselves and then gave back to SO? This has really discouraged me from ever doing that as I do it once and lose a lot of my rep (I currently have 168 so loosing 18 is big). What should I do?

Comment: I suppose you're referring to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000187/writing-a-tester-class-with-java

Answer (score 13):

Simply put, don't ask vague questions when you know they're vague. [Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41000187/1288) won't help anyone if nobody else can find it by searching for the problem that *they're* having.

Instead of posting a vague question and the answer you came up with, spend time improving the question to the point where someone else might be able to understand the problem well enough to help you. Once that's the case, it might be helpful to other people.

Comment: Ok thanks I removed my question